# Need to click Overflow Menu Item twice when other menu item in Action bar is selected

Tags: android

I am using Action bar and having menu items implemented using Action Provider. Clicking on menu item shows Popup Spinner. Now when any Menu item is clicked and Popup screen is ON and that time - If Overflow menu item is clicked then it doesn't show menu items under Overflow list (I need to click once again to get Overflow menu items).
Is this known issue? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this known issue?

It's known. It is not an issue. The drop-down for list navigation (what I presume the "Popup Spinner" is) has the focus. It takes a tap outside of the drop-down, anywhere in the activity, to dismiss the drop-down.

This is not significantly different than the behavior of a `Spinner` anywhere else in Android. For example, edit a contact, and tap on the `Spinner` to change a phone number type (e.g., mobile vs. home vs. work). It takes a tap anywhere else to dismiss the drop-down list, before a tap will have any other meaning.

> Is there any workaround for this?

Do not use list navigation or other `Spinners` in your app.